# MySQL - Filtro especial

Tags: mysql

Espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente. Tengo que realizar una consulta en una base de datos MySQL que contiene alertas de un sistema informático. Esta base, contiene el hostname, la cantidad de muestras con alerta y el mensaje de la alerta. En esta columna, existen unas alertas cuyo contenido contienen el texto **"EUE"**, y necesito que se muestren en una query solamente si el valor de `suppcount` es mayor a 3. El dilema es que las alertas que no contienen la sentencia EUE en el mensaje, deben aparecer sin importar el valor de `suppcount`. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo solucionar esto? De antemano, agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan proporcionar.

La query original es:

```
select 
suppcount as metrica,
hostname, 
message as descripcion,
from table1
where
hostname not like 'tfc%'
and
hostname not like 'prd2100%'
and
hostname not like 'prd7118%'
and
message not like '%vmsmt2063.smt.tchile.local%'
and
message not like '%TFCTOOL%'
and
message not like '%CPU%'
```

Esto resulta en algo como esto:

```
|métrica|hostname       |descripción                                    
|0      |prd7478        |DeltaError: Disk usage change on /data6, changed by -432.0 MB          
|0      |rbt-cpuhp1427  |EUE_GIT_Login Con problemas                            
|3      |usagedb01      |Conexion hacia NAS ISILON nasfssmt-amdocs.tchile.local San Martin con problemas
|0      |prd7808        |DeltaError: Disk usage change on /data8, changed by -875.0 MB          
|0      |prd7804        |DeltaError: Disk usage change on /data4, changed by 209.0 MB
```

Sin embargo, yo necesito que en las alertas que contengan la palabra EUE, solo se muestre en el caso que el conteo métrica, sea mayor a tres. Por ejemplo, la alerta `EUE_GIT_Login Con problemas`, debería desaparecer, ya que no cumple con la condición que debe tener para mostrarse aunque contenga el texto "EUE".
Encontré la forma de llegar a lo que quiero, pero claramente esta query solo me mostrará las alertas que contengan el texto "EUE" lo que no me sirve, ya que necesito como resultado todo el universo de alertas, y no sólo las que contengan EUE.

```
select hostname, 
suppcount as metrica,
message as descripcion,
from table1
where
message like '%EUE%'
and
suppcount > 3
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega la estructura de la tabla, la salida de datos que obtienes al momento y la salida que deberías estar obteniendo

Comment: No me queda muy claro, será algo así: `where (message like '%EUE%' and
suppcount > 3) or  (message not like '%EUE%' and
suppcount >= 1)` ?

Comment: Modifiqué la pregunta, tratando aportar mayor información. Sé que suena confuso, pero de todas maneras agradezco la ayuda otorgada hasta el momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz dos consultas, la primera para recuperar los mensajes que contengan el valor `EUE` con `suppcount > 3` y la segunda con todos los mensajes que no contengan `EUE` y únelas con un `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT 
 hostname, suppcount as metrica,message as descripcion,
FROM table1
WHERE
 message like '%EUE%' AND suppcount > 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 
 hostname, suppcount as metrica,message as descripcion,
FROM table1
WHERE
 message NOT LIKE '%EUE%'
```

Comment: Esto era precisamente lo que buscaba, muchas gracias por la ayuda estimado.

Answer (score 1):

Usa UNION o UNION ALL para juntar dos consultas SELECT. Dependiendo si quieres combinar o no las lineas repetidas.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id,
    a.unidade,
    a.posicao,
    a.nome,
    a.peso
FROM
    produtos a,
    produtos_pedidos b
WHERE
    a.id = b.id_produto
    and b.id_pedido IN (1,2)

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
    p.id,
    p.unidade,
    p.posicao,
    p.nome,
    p.peso
FROM
    produtos p,
    pedidos_barganha pb
WHERE
    p.id = pb.id_produto
    and pb.id_pedido IN (1,2)
ORDER BY nome
```

Esto te devuelve lo que quieres, en cada una filtras como quieres las cosas y el resultado va a ser como si fuera una sola consulta.

Comment: Esto sirve también para juntar consultas de dos tablas distintas?

Comment: Sirve si, es para juntar consultas, no importa si son o no de la misma tabla.